# Поиск внутри коллекции

Tags: java, поиск, коллекции

Как я могу искать внутри колллекции `List forFile = new ArrayList();`, если она состоит из объектов класса, в котором есть 4 приватных поля,

```
  private String name;
    private String hash;
    private int lastdate[] = new int[3];
    private int size;
```

Каким способом можно пройтись пройтись по объектам коллекции, что-бы найти элемент с самым большим `size`?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, какой толк от этой коллекции, если свойства объекта `private` и даже если будем перебирать эту коллекцию, то не сможем у объектов вызывать эти свойства так как они `private`.

Comment: Либо добавить геттер, либо играть в рефлексию

Comment: @And я заполняю объект класса через конструктор, и записываю в коллекцию  `forFile.add(new file(name, hash, lastDate, size));`.

Comment: Это не важно как вы заполняете, вы не сможете из объекта обратиться к этим полям. Либо сделать `enum` коллекцию или использовать константы. Ну или конечно-же, `getter` для обращения извне.

Comment: а) геттеры, б) если невозможно а), то `public` поля, в) если невозможно б), то получать значение с помощью рефлексии.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано, для доступа к приватному полю нужен геттер.

```
int getSize (){
return size;
}

        List forFile = new ArrayList();
        int indMax=0;
        int max= forFile.get(0).getSize();
        for( int i=1; i<forFile.size();i++){
            if (forFile.get(i).getSize()>max){
                max=forFile.get(i).getSize();
                indMax=i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: чувствуется с JAVA вы не работали. Не используете foreach, stream api)

Comment: @Санаев человеку который разбирается в основах кидать stream api не слишком ли? А вообще форум для информации, а не для обсуждения кто лучше, кто хуже

Comment: ок, тогда foreach чем плох?

Comment: @Санаев необходим номер объекта с максимальным size

Comment: Зачем? Не понимаю вас

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class YourClass{
       private String name;
       private String hash;
       private int lastdate[] = new int[3];
       private int size;

       public int getSize(){
         return size;
       }
    }
```

***Дальше перебираешь так:***

```
    List<YourClass> yourClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    //заполнение yourClassList
    //...
    Integer maxSize = yourClassList.stream().mapToInt(s->s.getSize()).max().getAsInt();
```

Comment: вам что-то не нравится?) или вы просто так дизлайк ставите?

Comment: Вроде все верно) @Санаев

Comment: Как по мне это напоминает использование микроскопа для того, чтобы понять, что за человек перед тобой. Я имею в виду, что это можно сделать и глазами.

Comment: Минус был не мой, если что, но я не одобряю такой подход, пока это не разрастется до большого проекта

Comment: @iamthevoid я так понимаю у автора учебный проект

Comment: @iamthevoid а как бы вы сделали? использовали функциональный интерфейс, создали бы универсальный метод? или что?

Comment: да обычный геттер. Не нарушает инкапсуляции и выглядит симпатично. А добавлять в проект аннотейшн прецесор, который генерит миллион геттеров для pojo, это излишне в учебном проекте, имхо

Comment: @iamthevoid согласен, но по-моему его не нужно подключать до 9 версии jdk

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69902/discussion-between--and-iamthevoid).